# NDVI colour scheme for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modis, color, ndvi

Does anyone have a download link for the NDVI colour scheme to use in ArcGIS for Desktop?

I am looking for MODIS mod13 data and cannot find an appropriate colour scheme in the programme.

Comment: see http://skipper-blog.blogspot.ca/2014/02/modis-enhanced-vegetation-index-evi.html

Comment: i found that, its an evi colour scheme though, is there one for an ndvi colour scheme?

Comment: A Google Image search of ["NDVI Map"](https://www.google.com.au/search?biw=1920&bih=1075&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=ndvi+map&oq=ndvi+map&gs_l=img.3..0j0i24.7675.8450.0.9024.4.4.0.0.0.0.207.409.2-2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.img..2.2.408.NM1KWp4w0sU) yields many different results.  From shades of green and brown to all the colours of the rainbow.  So, I don't think there is a standard colour scheme. However, I think shades of green make the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a universally accepted color scheme for NDVI visualization. You can pick whatever you prefer as long as it is not counterintuitive. For example, many papers use different shades of green to indicate different levels of NDVI values.